# Replace values in in a string variable, if presence, coded as 1 in a new dummy variable

Tags: r, string

I have a dataset that looks like the following:

```
id. string
1   US-EU-MX
2   EU-MX-US
3   US-MX-CA
```

How do I make a dummy variable based on whether the string contains "EU" so that the final dataset would look like the following?

```
id. string   dummy
1   US-EU-MX  1
2   EU-MX-US  1
3   US-MX-CA  0
```

Thanks, yall!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `grepl` to find a pattern and convert the logical values to integer.

```
df$dummy <- as.integer(grepl('EU', df$string))
df

#  id.   string dummy
#1   1 US-EU-MX     1
#2   2 EU-MX-US     1
#3   3 US-MX-CA     0
```

Using `as.integer` on logical values is shorter and faster way than using `ifelse`.

```
df$dummy <- ifelse(grepl('EU', df$string), 1, 0)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(id. = 1:3, string = c("US-EU-MX", "EU-MX-US", 
"US-MX-CA")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `+`

```
df$dummy <- +(grepl('EU', df$string))
```